# I can't delete a native App Registration in Azure AD portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I just want to delete an AD app registration that I create for testing purpose. I can't delete it because the delete button is grayed out. Before I deleted another not used application without any problems!
Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can visit the Microsoft Application Console and try to delete it.

[image]

[image]

Refresh after 20-30 secs, your native app will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me. It's worth noting that although I was prompted to login with a Microsoft account, my Azure AD account worked fine.

Answer (score 51):

A bit late to the game, but when trying the above steps, they wouldn't work for me (was always disabled, and for some reason, I couldn't add myself as the owner, even though I'm global admin in that Azure AD tenant).

I came across this blog post which I think is the correct answer: 
[Unable to remove app registrations in Azure AD](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/unable-remove-app-registrations-aad/)

The gist of it:

**Web api**

- Go to the app registration
- Open up properties
- Find multi-tenanted option, set it to no
- Save
- Delete

**Native app**

- Go to the app registration
- Open up the manifest
- Click on Edit
- Find 'availableToOtherTenants', change that to false
- Save
- Delete

*I hate copy/pasting another person's blog post as an answer, but it's what got me going. Send him a shout out on his blog.*

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. In my case, I had registered Power BI REST API applications using Native app option. This was mainly for testing purpose so I needed to leave the stage clean... I can confirm this worked in my case. Simply modifying 'availableToOtherTenants' property from true to false and then saving the manifest did the trick. Delete button was then enabled and I then could proceed with Delete operation. Piece of cake. Thanks

Comment: availableToOtherTenants - set to false, done. thank you.

Comment: This should be the right answer. The Ms App Console is not available anymore.

Answer (score 8):

I am able to delete web api app by changing manifest

To delete the native application, open the manifest editor and set below field to false

availableToOtherTenants=false

Comment: You are basically changing the manifest when you change it using the editor. So the statement "able to change without changing the manifest" is logically contradictory.

Comment: Thanks.. It was typo

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was not able to delete via Azure app registrations, but when switched to App Registrations (Preview), delete button was active.
As this is ever changing cloud environment, answers change over time

Azure portal screenshot:

[image: azure portal screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this, but the apps didn't show up on Application Console under `My apps`.  Also the apps didn't show up on Azure App Registrations under `My apps` either, I had to choose the drop down for `All apps`.  I had to first edit the Azure App Registration and add myself as the Owner.  (`Settings > Owners...`).  Then I was able to see if on Application Console as `My apps` and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete it under "Enterprise applications" under Azure Active Directory in the new portal. Put in the App ID in the search field, click the row and then click the delete button from the toolbar.

Comment: Deleting it from Enterprise Applications did not remove it from App Registrations in my case. I had to change the manifest as per above answers in order to get proper rid of it.