# Registered App Delete button disabled in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to delete an Azure directory. 
In order to do this I must first delete all app registrations.
In the App registration blade, when I show All Apps, there is an app called LocationSvcClient.
When I drill into this I see the delete button is disabled.
I would have created the directory using the subscription that came with Visual Studio Professional.
There is no longer a subscription associated with the directory.
The app has no service principal and no owners. I have removed all permissions. I have removed all redirect URLs

The manifest settings are ( edited *** )

```
    {
  "appId": "***",
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": false,
  "displayName": "LocationSvcClient",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": null,
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "acceptMappedClaims": null,
  "homepage": null,
  "informationalUrls": {
    "privacy": null,
    "termsOfService": null
  },
  "identifierUris": [],
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
  "oauth2Permissions": [],
  "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
  "objectId": "***",
  "parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
  },
  "passwordCredentials": [],
  "publicClient": true,
  "replyUrls": [],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't delete a native App Registration in Azure AD portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081928/i-cant-delete-a-native-app-registration-in-azure-ad-portal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I drill into this I see the delete button is disabled.

1.If it's a multi-tenant app,the delete button will be disabled, you need to convert it back to a single-tenant app before you can delete it.

[image]

Settings>Properties>set Multi-tenanted to No

[image]

Then you can delete it.

[image]

2.If your app type is native, you can manually add the `availableToOtherTenants` setting via Manifest and edit the setting. Then you could delete the app.

[image]

3.You can use **Microsoft Application Console** to try to delete it.

For more detail, you can refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081928/i-cant-delete-a-native-app-registration-in-azure-ad-portal).

Comment: I went to settings->Properties but there is no Multi-tenanted option

Comment: @kirsteng I can find it from App registrations>your app name>Settings>Properties>Multi-tenanted(at the bottom of the page).You can see my update.

Comment: The Applicatoin Type is Native
Maybe that is why I don't see the Multi-tenanted option.

Comment: @kirsteng This is related to the availableToOtherTenants setting, you could follow my update to edit the setting.

Comment: I tried changing the setting but it did not help.  I updated the question to show the settings.

Comment: @kirsteng I find an article,may be it could help.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081928/i-cant-delete-a-native-app-registration-in-azure-ad-portal)

Comment: Thank you Joy. Strange. I was able to delete it using the App registrations Screen but not when I drilled down into properties. I guess that makes this question a duplicate.